# Gamestates causing my game to bug

Tags: c#, debugging, xna

So I am using Gamestates in my game, and I am having an error when reaching the game over or win screen. I have tried to code it so that when you press <kbd>M</kbd>, it goes back to the original main menu so you can start playing over again.
However, on pressing <kbd>M</kbd>, the game seems to bug and the main menu just constantly flashes and when it does stop, you click play, and it takes you back to the gameover or win screen! I've tried debugging it but have come to no avail. I shall try adding the relevant code below.

In Update:

```
switch (CurrentGameState)
{
    case GameState.MainMenu:
        if (btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
        btnPlay.Update(mouse);

        if (btnInstructions.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Instructions;
        btnInstructions.Update(mouse);
        break;

    case GameState.Instructions:
        if (instrPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
        instrPlay.Update(mouse);
        break;

    case GameState.Playing:       
        //functions for game playing here

        #region game over
        if (hastouched2 > 0 && Ball.ballPos.Y > 740 || hastouched3 > 0 && Ball.ballPos.Y > 740 || Box == null && Ball.ballPos.Y > 740)
            CurrentGameState = GameState.Gameover;

        #endregion
        break;

    case GameState.Gameover:
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.M))  
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;            
        break;

    case GameState.YouWin:
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.M))
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
        break;
}

base.Update(gameTime);
```

In draw:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case GameState.MainMenu:
            spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("mainMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
            btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
            btnInstructions.Draw(spriteBatch);
            break;

        case GameState.Instructions:
            spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("instructions_screen"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
            instrPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
            break;

        case GameState.Playing:
            spriteBatch.Draw(background, bgPos, Color.White);
            if (Box != null)
            {
                Box.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            if (Box2 != null)
            {
                Box2.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            if (Box3 != null)
            {
                Box3.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            break;

        case GameState.Gameover:
            spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("gameover"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
            break;

        case GameState.YouWin:
            spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("youwin"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
            break;
```

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: First of all, if you have a problem you should try posting the relevant code, and not a link to your whole project, you should do an effort. And what do you mean with "reset null objects"? If you need them again you can create new instance of them.

Comment: Anyway, if the game takes you back to the gameover or win screen when you restart it, you probably don't set gamestate to something different to "Gameover", or whatever. You should add the code you use to restart the game.

Comment: will attempt to add the relevant code now

Comment: added some relevant code, hopefully this is more helpful?

Comment: Based on your code, my guess is that in your GamePlaying code, you don't properly reset the game, so when you reach the end of the block, you are still in the game over state according to the ball position. If not, this might at least give you an idea where to look.

Comment: Any idea if there is an easier way to go about 'restarting the game' or resetting the variables. I am trying to reset every single variable  in the GameOver and YouWin gamestates however am finding it hard to find every single variable and then find it original state and re set it..?

Answer (score 0):

This thing

```
if (hastouched2 > 0 && Ball.ballPos.Y > 740 || hastouched3 > 0 && Ball.ballPos.Y > 740 || Box == null && Ball.ballPos.Y > 740)
```

triggers the gameover.

But when you set `GameState.Playing` you should reset every variable and `Ball.ballPos` or you will return in gameover state. The same thing happens with `GameState.YouWin`.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try that - do I need to reset all the objects that have been turned to null? (If so is that just a case of re calling it?) Cheers once again

Comment: Probably you will need to re-create new instance of them, as it was the first time you start your game.

Comment: Any idea if there is an easier way to go about 'restarting the game' or resetting the variables. I am trying to reset every single variable  in the GameOver and YouWin gamestates however am finding it hard to find every single variable and then find it original state and re set it..?

Comment: You should have a class that manages your whole game, something as a sprite manager or similar. When you start your game from the main menu what class do you use? You should only need to create a new instance of that class and every variable will be reset.

Comment: Yeah I'm quite new to programming so my code is messy and don't think I've laid my code out in such an organized way. After trying to objects and variables it's better but not doing what I needed, oh well!

Comment: I hope you haven't everything in your Game1 class, that will be a problem.

Comment: Not everything but yes, A lot of things I think are so my bad code organization has done me over.